# Locating jar from gradle build in Mac

Tags: macos, spring-boot, gradle, gradlew

I am fairly new with Mac. I am trying to build a jar file for my spring boot project. I ran ./gradlew on terminal. Now I am unsure where to find jar. I cant locate build directory in my project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jar generated should be in :

```
project
   - > build
          -> libs
                 project.jar
```

Comment: I stated that I cant locate build directory in project directory

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped.

Comment: Okay if my answer helped you please mark it as answer. Kind regards

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. Didn't know the protocols.